# IndexError: index 440 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 440 in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
----> 1 create_tf_record_2D(training_set, train_tfrec2D, LABELS)
      2 create_tf_record_2D(test_set, test_tfrec2D, LABELS)
      3 create_tf_record_2D(validation_set, val_tfrec2D, LABELS)
```

in create_tf_record_2D(img_filenames, tf_rec_filename, labels)

```
     19 
     20     # load the image and label
---> 21     img, label = load_image_2D(meta_data, labels)
     22 
     23     # create a feature
```

in load_image_2D(abs_path, labels)

```
     27 
     28   # make the 2D image
---> 29   img = slices_matrix_2D(img)
     30 
     31   return img, label
```

in slices_matrix_2D(img)

```
     44     for i in range(cut.shape[0]):
     45       for j in range(cut.shape[1]):
---> 46         image_2D[i + row_it, j + col_it] = cut[i, j]
     47     row_it += cut.shape[0]
     48
```

IndexError: index 440 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 440

Comment: It gives such an error when trying to convert 3D MRI images to 2D.

Comment: For any 1D array of length N, an index must be 0 <= index < N. In your case, index == N hence the IndexError is raised

Comment: # copy the cut to the 2D image
    for i in range(cut.shape[0]):
      for j in range(cut.shape[1]):
        image_2D[i + row_it, j + col_it] = cut[i, j]
    row_it += cut.shape[0]                                                                                                                   here it gives "IndexError: index 440 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 440"   @Ofek Glick

Comment: how can i fix it so i am a bit of a beginner  @DarkKnight